# selection of at least one check box is must in angular js? I did not get the perfect answer of this how we can do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

form is not valid and check box is not selected then the button should be disabled.This is my code and it is not working according to my conditions.where should I make correction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module("my_app",[])
.controller("my_controller",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.cities={};
        $scope.user={
            full_time:true,
        };
        })
</script>


<div ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_controller">
  <form name="frm">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.part_time"/> <label>part_time</label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.full_time" value="full_time" /> <label>full_time</label> 
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.traing" value="training" /> <label>traing_time</label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.one_time" value="one_time" /> <label>one_time</label> <br>


        <input type="submit" value="click here" ng-disabled="((frm.invalid) || ((user.full_time) || (user.part_time) || (user.one_time) || (user.traing) ))"  />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only part that I have to change is

```
<input type="submit" value="click here" ng-disabled="((frm.invalid) || ((user.full_time) || (user.part_time) || (user.one_time) || (user.traing) ))"  />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="click here" ng-disabled="!((frm.invalid) || ((user.full_time) || (user.part_time) || (user.one_time) || (user.traing) ))"  />
```

only !(not) is added ng-disabled="!((frm.invalid)

and now it is working fine